# Rails 4: Use MySql and MongoDB together

Tags: mysql, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid4

I'm trying to make an application in rails 4 using MongoDB(mongoid) and MySQL together.
But I'm not able to set it up.

I'm following the steps below:

1. `rails new myapp -d mysql`
2. Then added these lines to Gemfile:
    `gem "mongoid"`
    `gem "bson_ext"`
3. `bundle install`
4. `rails g mongoid:config`

The step 4 fails. I'm not able to figure out the problem. It shows the following error.

> /home/devesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/mongoid-1.0.6/lib/mongoid/associations.rb:5:in `require': /home/devesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/mongoid-1.0.6/lib/mongoid/associations/has_many.rb:79: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_cond, expecting ':'
>           @documents = attributes ? attributes.collect do |attrs|
>                                                          ^
>   /home/devesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/mongoid-1.0.6/lib/mongoid/associations/has_many.rb:84: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
>           end : []
>                ^
>   /home/devesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/mongoid-1.0.6/lib/mongoid/associations/has_many.rb:99: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_cond, expecting keyword_end
>           attributes.values.each do |attrs|
>                                    ^
>   /home/devesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/mongoid-1.0.6/lib/mongoid/associations/has_many.rb:139: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)
>       from /home/devesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/mongoid-1.0.6/lib/mongoid/associations.rb:5:in`'
>       from /home/devesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/mongoid-1.0.6/lib/mongoid.rb:40:in `require'
>       from /home/devesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/mongoid-1.0.6/lib/mongoid.rb:40:in`'
>       from /home/devesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
>       from /home/devesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in`block (2 levels) in require'
>       from /home/devesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
>       from /home/devesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in`block in require'
>       from /home/devesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
>       from /home/devesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in`require'
>       from /home/devesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
>       from /home/devesh/fashion_hub/store/config/application.rb:7:in`'
>       from /home/devesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `require'
>       from /home/devesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in`preload'
>       from /home/devesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
>       from /home/devesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in`block in run'
>       from /home/devesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
>       from /home/devesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in`run'
>       from /home/devesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /home/devesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'
>       from /home/devesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'

I was following this [url](https://sachkadam.wordpress.com/2013/05/03/setup-a-rails-app-to-use-both-mongodb-and-mysql-together/).

Some details:

1. OS - ubuntu 14.04
2. ruby v2.2.2
3. rails 4.2.3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add these line to your `application.rb` file:
`config.generators do |g|
    g.orm :active_record
 end`

This will force rails g to use active record.

And whenever you want to generate a model for mongodb, use:

`rails g mongoid:model yourmodelname`

Comment: but then how I will create any model in mongoid ?