# Postgres and MongoDB together in the same project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to have Postgresql and MongoDB in the same project ? 
I would like to be able to use generators for both as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can have multiple database.yml files, etc.

There are a number of articles about getting multiple dbs set up in Rails.
http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/managing-multiple-databases-in-a-single-rails-application/
http://www.ostinelli.net/setting-multiple-databases-rails-definitive-guide/

In terms of using generators this post should help: [Rails 4: Use MySql and MongoDB together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32008513/rails-4-use-mysql-and-mongodb-together#answer-32032655)

Comment: I didn't find this link that was already on Stack. It was very useful.

Comment: Could you also explain how to deal with migrations and optimizing number of connections in the pool to avoid duplicates due to misconfigured models. Cheerios